# How to reset a socket error #10054 in Delphi 10.4

Tags: multithreading, sockets, delphi

We are using a TCPIP connection. A gPinstamper1ThreadComponent := TIdThreadComponent.Create() is started.
When the connection is lost (cable not connected), the Socket Error #10054 is coming. At that moment also the Thread has stopped.
How to reset the Error (after connecting the cable again) and how to restart the Thread.

I hope that you can help me,

Best Regards,
Johannes

restarting the Thread, but always running into the Error.

Answer (score 2):

You can't just reset the socket error. `10054` is a fatal error, the connection is dead. You have to fully close the socket and create a new one. Assuming you are using `TIdTCPClient`, just `Disconnect()` it, `Clear()` its `InputBuffer` of any unread data, and re-`Connect()` it.

You can't restart a thread once it has terminated. You have to close it and start a new thread. For `TIdThreadComponent`, that means calling its `Stop()` and `Start()` methods, or toggling its `Active` property to `False` and then back to `True`.

For what you are attempting, I would suggest setting the `TIdThreadComponent` to `Loop=True`, where each loop iteration connects the TCP client, does its work, and then disconnects, with adequate error handling to prevent the thread from terminating.